# How to open a link which is inside a modal, in the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have modal which is rendering a markdown :

```
<div class="markdown">

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade in">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Header</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
        Some content in here

     Some links here
     <p>Link1</p>
     <p>Link2</p>
     <p>Link3</p>
   </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
     </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Now, my problem is that when I click on any of the links : it refreshes the browser if used href .

I want to open the links inside the modal, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: What type of links are they? are the links for ajax requests or standard links to any webpage? Will regular web pages display nicely in your modal?

Comment: What the links are supposed to do?

Comment: Do an $.ajax() call, on success $('#modal').html(content);

Answer (score 1):

use this command instead of `data-dismiss="modal"` in link

```
onclick="$('#squarespaceModal').modal('hide')"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using a jQuery ajax method such as `.load()` to get the content from the link and load it into the `.modal-body` or `.modal-content`..

```
$('.lnk').click(function(){
  var lnk = $(this).data("src");
  $('.modal-body').text('wait..');
  $('.modal-body').load(lnk,function(){

  });
})
```

You'd change the links to this...

```
<div class="modal-body">
      <a href="#" data-src="/url" class="lnk">Link1</a>
      <a href="#" data-src="/url1" class="lnk">Link1</a>
      <a href="#" data-src="/url2" class="lnk">Link1</a>
</div>
```

Demo: **http://bootply.com/87874**

**Another method:**

Use `iframe` and jQuery to dynamically change the src of the frame: http://bootply.com/61676